# toggleClass function not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

My function is not working properly. sometimes it work sometimes it not

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){

    $('label').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('jaja papa')
    }   )


    })

</script>

</head>

<body>

<label class="jaja">
<input type="checkbox" />
click
</label>

</body>
```

Comment: yes exactly. i want to swap class

Comment: But it is not working properly on lable. when i use p tag instead of label then it work fine

Comment: I cant see any errors in the code snippet why it shouldn't work properly.

Comment: Works fine in isolation: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVCM5/

Comment: please check it again with input type checkbox http://jsfiddle.net/ZVCM5/1/

Comment: @amit - ok, now I see the problem. Looking again.

Comment: why voting down, did I ask something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the label, you're also clicking the checkbox because that's what a label does. The click event of the checkbox in turn bubbles up to the label. So, the click handler of the label is fired twice and the classes are toggled twice, effectively doing nothing.

You'd have to keep track of how many times the click handler is called and only acts the first time: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVCM5/2/.

```
$('label').click(function f(e) {
    if(!f.triggered) {  // only if not already triggered for this time
        f.triggered = true;
        $(this).toggleClass('jaja papa');
        setTimeout(function() {
            f.triggered = false;  // reset after both clicks are done
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: But when i am using span instead of label then why it is working fine

Comment: @amit: Yes, because a span is "just" an element. A label has the additional property that it clicks the element inside (try it).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution, which involves changing your markup slightly (for the better IMHO!)

If you were to change the label to have the checkbox and a span with the text - and apply your style there instead, ie:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="papa">Test</span>
</label>
```

Then this jQuery works:

```
$('label>:checkbox').click(function(){
    $(this).next('span').toggleClass('jaja papa')
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/JHwBP/

Advantage here is that you have more addressable HTML (you can get to the text separately from the checkbox inside a label). Also the semantics of clicking the text still checks/unchecks the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle between those two classess

```
$('label').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('jaja').toggleClass('papa');
    });
```

Should do it

Comment: The docs say space separated class names are allowed.

Comment: Although correct, there is no reason to separate them.

Comment: separated class names are allowed but that would toggle both of them at once

Comment: @pimvdb Here is what the spec says `<div class="tumble">Some text.</div>`

Applying `.toggleClass('bounce spin')` to the same `<div>` alternates between `<div class="tumble bounce spin">` and `<div class="tumble">`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ somewhere in the middle of the page

Comment: @Clyde Lobo: That's what I mean. And if `bounce` was already there, it would be toggling `bounce` and `spin`, like the OP wants.